# How to use the same pdf-tools install on OSX and Linux simultaneously?

Tags: osx, linux, pdf-tools

**Q:** how can I get `pdf-tools` to work simultaneously on OSX and Linux?

I keep my `.emacs.d` directory synced over Dropbox, and share it between machines running OSX and Linux (Fedora and Ubuntu).  I got `pdf-tools` off of melpa and successfully installed it on OSX.

The problem is that `pdf-tools` creates an executable (`epdfinfo`) in its melpa directory.  The executable it generates on OSX is not usable on the Linux machines (and I presume vice versa).

*How can I get `pdf-tools` to play nice across the different systems?  Can I (should I) generate another executable on the Linux machines to store in the same directory, and if so, how?*

The nuclear option, I believe, is to remove the melpa package, go old school, and install `pdf-tools` by hand -- but do it twice, once for OSX, and once for the Linux systems, and then do some system checking at startup to see which one to use.  That seems like a lot of fuss.

Answer (score 2):

I guess one option is to add a `.gitignore` which prevents Git from tracking that executable.  The downside of course is that it will force you to re-build that executable on every machine.

Another is to set `pdf-info-epdfinfo-program` to a filename that includes some system info, such as `(expand-file-name (concat "epdfinfo-" system-type) ...)` and then to rename those executables accordingly.  You'll probably also want to adjust the above code since `system-type` can be `gnu/linux` where the slash is rather inconvenient.